# CSS/JS Slider Code Blocking CSS/JS Overlay

Tags: javascript, css

I have a CSS/JS image slider that seems to be preventing the CSS/JS automatic overlay popup (for a newsletter subscription) I had on the site previously.

The slider works with or without the pop-up code; but with the slider code on the page, the pop-up will not work, and will work again as soon as I remove the slider code.

My understanding of JS is very limited, so I have tried everything I can think of and have made no progress.

Relevant code is below, and page in question is http://www.catalystathletics.com (pop-up should only appear on first visit unless browser is cleared).

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

```
<!-- HEADER SLIDER -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_inc/slider/slippry.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/_inc/slider/slippry.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#headerSlider').slippry();
});
</script>
<!-- END HEADER SLIDER -->




<!-- SUBSCRIPTION POPUP -->
    <link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" target="_blank" href="/_inc/subPopup/colorbox.css" />
    <!-- Style For the Subscription Box -->
    <link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" target="_blank" href="/_inc/subPopup/popup.css" />
    <!-- <script language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
    <script language="javascript" src="/_inc/subPopup/colorbox.js"></script>
<script>
$("document").ready(function (){ 

       // load the overlay

        if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1) {
            var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*15;
            var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
            document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
            $.colorbox({width:"580px", inline:true, href:"#subscribe_popup"});
        }

        $(".open_popup").colorbox({width:"580px", inline:true, href:"#subscribe_popup"});

 });
</script>
<!-- END SUBSCRIPTION POPUP -->
```

Comment: there seems to be an error in colorbox.js with some property called msie, check devtools and console

Comment: Thanks, needed an updated colorbox version

Answer (score 0):

You are using older version of [colorbox](https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox), as console logs "`TypeError: a.browser is undefined`", try updating your color box plugin to latest version. If that does not fix the issue, try using [jquery-migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate) script, as:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Updated the original colorbox.js file with the new one from http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/ and now both slider and pop up are working with just this http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Hey it should be work if you use `jquery and colorbox js updated version`
i edited on `js fiddle` its working good as you need.

you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/abidkhanweb/5456sxLa/